# No puedo hacer que mi codigo funcione por partes

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y ni bien empiezo ya me encuentro con un problemilla.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // Your code here!
                        
        int primerNumero=1;
        int ultimoNumero=10;

        while (primerNumero<=ultimoNumero){
            System.out.println(primerNumero);
            primerNumero++;
        }
        
        while (primerNumero<=ultimoNumero){
            if (primerNumero % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(primerNumero);
            }
            primerNumero++;     
        }       
    }
}
```

aca cada parte funciona bien individualmente pero asi como esta me imprime solo lo de arriba. Como hago que me muestre ambas tareas?? Gracias!!

Comment: Cuando termina el primer `While` te queda `primerNumero =11`, por eso no entra al segundo `While`

Comment: Realmente llega en 11

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Claro, toda la razón (yo siempre dije 11 :P)

Comment: @yussef Mil gracias, ahora que me lo decis me doy cuenta. Estoy muy verde jajajaja

Comment: Como que te conviene usar un `for` en este ejercicio

Comment: Efectivamente bastaría un ```for`` que inicialice la el contador a ```1```. ¿pensé que lo había puesto en mi comentario?  :P

Answer (score 0):

Solución A (no me gusta):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
   int primerNumeroA = 1;
   int primerNumeroB = 1;
   int ultimoNumero = 10;
   while( primerNumeroA <= ultimoNumero ) {
      System.out.println( primerNumeroA );
      primerNumeroA ++;
   }
   while( primerNumeroB <= ultimoNumero ) {
      if( primerNumeroB % 2 == 0 ) {
         System.out.println( primerNumeroB );
      }
      primerNumeroB ++;
   }
}
```

Solución B:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
   int primerNumero = 1;
   int ultimoNumero = 10;
   Main main = new Main();
   main.metodoA( primerNumero, ultimoNumero );
   main.metodoB( primerNumero, ultimoNumero );  
}

void metodoA( int primerNumero, int ultimoNumero ) {
    while( primerNumero <= ultimoNumero ) {
        System.out.println( primerNumero );
        primerNumero ++;
   }
}

void metodoB( int primerNumero, int ultimoNumero ) {
    while( primerNumero <= ultimoNumero ) {
        if( primerNumero % 2 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println( primerNumero );
        }
        primerNumero ++;
   }
}
```

Como podés ver, en la primera solución, simplemente declaramos dos variables para iniciar y usamos una en cada while.
No me gusta porque estamos en un entorno POO, entonces porqué privarnos de sus ventajas?.
En la segunda solución, opto por hacer código reutilizable, por eso creo dos métodos, a los que puedo llamar desde cualquier "lugar".
Para invocarlos, y no tener que crear innecesariamente métodos estáticos, creo un objeto de la clase, y mediante el los invoco.

Comment: Te falto llamar al método B

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, gracias maestro!!!

Comment: Modificar los parámetros de un método directamente no es una buena práctica. Tu ejemplo funciona únicamente porque `int` es un primitivo y java los trata de una manera un poco especial... si pasases un objeto y modificases sus atributos estarías modificándolos también fuera de tu método, lo cual puede provocar errores inesperados.

Answer (score 0):

una manera en la cual puedas acceder al segundo While es reiniciando la variable primerNumero, nuevamente a 1. De tal manera que cuando termine el primer ciclo pueda iniciar con el segundo e imprimir sin problemas. Esto se da ya que como utilizas la misma variable para el conteo del segundo While es necesario reiniciarla puesto que en el primer While la estas llenando.

```html
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // Your code here!
                        
        int primerNumero=1;
        int ultimoNumero=10;

        while (primerNumero<=ultimoNumero){
            System.out.println(primerNumero);
            primerNumero++;
        }
        
        /*Aqui hacer el reinicio de la variable para poder iniciar el segundo         ciclo While*/
        primerNumero=1;
        
        while (primerNumero<=ultimoNumero){
            if (primerNumero % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(primerNumero);
            }
            primerNumero++;     
        }       
    }
}
```